# Passing POST params using JsonArrayRequest

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I've got a little PHP file written up that runs a search on a database:

```
<?php$host = "localhost"; // host of MySQL server
$user = "root"; // MySQL user
$pwd = "root"; // MySQL user's password
$db = "android_api"; // database name

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];


// query the application data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR phone LIKE '%$keyword%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Which, for the time being, seems to be working properly.

Now, in my Android app, I want to call a JsonArrayRequest using the Volley library to then populate a Listview with the results. My problem is, it's not sending the keyword as POST param, so my server is just returning every user in the table. Here's my getResults() method, which receives the string 'keyword':

```
private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(final String keyword)
    {

        pDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.searching_dialog));
        pDialog.show();

        final ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_SEARCH, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
                        sr1.setPhone(jsonObject.getString("phone"));
                        sr1.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        sr1.setSurname1(jsonObject.getString("surname1"));
                        sr1.setSurname2(jsonObject.getString("surname2"));
                        sr1.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("email"));
                        sr1.setImage(decodeBase64(jsonObject.getString("image")));
                        sr1.setUid(jsonObject.getString("unique_id"));
                        results.add(sr1);


                        //names.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //nameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(results.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.string.no_search_results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                else
                {
                    welcomeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pDialog.hide();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array");
            }

        }        )
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("keyword", keyword );

                return params;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        return results;
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing? Why is my code ignoring the keyword I'm sending?

Thanks

Comment: You did not tell which data the php file is receiving now. Why doesn't it check the value of $keyword before use?

Comment: '(final String keyword)'. You are not using keyword in your post. So what are you posting what you call 'parameters'?

Comment: You mean using if(isset($_POST['keyword'])? And, the method is called in a button's OnClick method, as String keyword = searchText.getText().toString().trim(); and then ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults(keyword);

Comment: Both your reactions are not to the point. Of course you will first use isset() and not continue if the variable is not set but give an error message. If it is set $keyword can be empty. So do not continue then either but echo an error message. You did not answer my question about 'GetSearchResults(keyword); '. You are not using the value of keyword inside that function. So you are not posting not only keyword but also not other parameters. You are sendinf an empty post.

Comment: I'm using keyword where getParams() is Overrided, near the bottom, after the error listener. This is the way I've seen other people use it online, on other questions or tutorials. Isn't this what's getting posted to the PHP code?

Comment: Ok. I overlooked that. Why are you talking about 'parameters' where you have only one? Have you checked with isset() if your parameter is set? Please report. Add it to your code also. Why didn't you give all this info already? React to what people suggest you to do please.

Comment: I've added if isset() to my PHP, with its corresponding else{} echoing out an error, and it seems the parameter is not being set. I've also edited the text in the original post to clarify that what I want to POST is just the keyword.

Comment: You could better name Volley in the subject of your post. Then google for volley posting parameters. A year ago about volley could not post. You will find posts on this site about that.